# strtotime() is adding 40+ years when using "+5 days"

Tags: php, strtotime

`$searchTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (time() + strtotime("+5 day")));`

printing searchTime returns `2058-02-04 05:26:12`. Any Idea why?

time() returns the correct time so it's not the problem.

Comment: Not surprising: you're adding the timestamp for 5 days hence to todays timestamp. Try simply `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+5 days"));`

Comment: Silly me. Never thought to consider that strtotime might be relative.

Comment: Reading the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) helps: `relative to the timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied. `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're effectively adding the timestamp of "today" (`time()`) to the timestamp of "today + 5 days" (`strtotime('+5 day')`) which, given that the timestamp of "today" is ~40+ years from 0, that makes sense. You can read about [`Unix time` here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) for a more in-depth explanation regarding the "starting time".

To fix this, remove the `time() +` portion and just use the return value of `strtotime('+5 day')`:

```
$searchTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+5 day"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're adding the time right now, to the time 5 days from now.

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+5 day"));
// 2014-01-24 15:52:04
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 $searchTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+5 day"));
```